# Error: At least one field must be set for HatomEntry

Tags: php

i have been trying to fix these errors in googles snippet test. I have been looking in the single.php file but cant seem to correct it.

```
hatom-entry:    
Error: At least one field must be set for HatomEntry.
Error: Missing required field "entry-title".
Error: Missing required field "updated".
Error: Missing required hCard "author".
Error: At least one field must be set for HatomEntry.
Error: Missing required field "entry-title".
Error: Missing required field "updated".
Error: Missing required hCard "author".
```

here is my single.php code:

```
<?php

/*  Small Business Theme's Single Page to display Single Page or Post
    Copyright: 2012-2013, D5 Creation, www.d5creation.com
    Based on the Simplest D5 Framework for WordPress
    Since Small Business 1.0
*/


get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

          <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <h3 class="subtitle"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sb_subtitle', 'true'); ?></h3>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <p class="postmetadataw">Posted by: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> |  on <span class="post_date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p> 

            <div class="content-ver-sep"> </div>
            <div class="entrytext"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumb'); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <div class="clear"> </div>
            <div class="up-bottom-border">
            <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php the_tags('<br />Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?></p>
            <?php  wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . 'Pages:' . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            <div class="content-ver-sep"> </div>
            <div class="floatleft"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link (Previous Post)'); ?></div>
            <div class="floatright"><?php next_post_link('(Next Post) %link &raquo;'); ?></div><br />
            <div class="floatleft"><?php previous_image_link( false, '&laquo; Previous Image' ); ?></div>
            <div class="floatright"><?php next_image_link( false, 'Next Image &raquo;' ); ?></div> 
            </div></div>

            <?php endwhile;?>

          <!-- End the Loop. -->          

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

</div>          
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is looking for specific classes on those elements based on hAtom micro-format standards:

http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom/

In your case, you'd want to change:

```
<h1 class="page-title">
```

to:

```
<h1 class="page-title entry-title">
```

and change:

```
<span class="post_date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
```

to:

```
<time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ) ?>" class="updated"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></time>
```

Make sure to use 'Y-m-d' for the datetime attribute, as this is the standard format required there.

hCard author fields require a little more markup, but are covered pretty thoroughly here:

http://microformats.org/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

you don't necessarily need to modify single.php file. you can use plugins like "schema-creator" to include rich snippet in your posts/pages and to solve the hatom error in google web master, you will need to add this piece of code to the function.php file in your theme's directory

```
//mod content
function hatom_mod_post_content ($content) {
if ( in_the_loop() && !is_page() ) {
$content = '<span class="entry-content">'.$content.'</span>';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'hatom_mod_post_content');

//add hatom data
function add_mod_hatom_data($content) {
$t = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$author = get_the_author();
$title = get_the_title();
if(is_single()) {
    $content .= '<div class="hatom-extra"><span class="entry-title">'.$title.'</span> was    last modified: <span class="updated"> '.$t.'</span> by <span class="author vcard"><span class="fn">'.$author.'</span></span></div>';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_mod_hatom_data');
```

The code contains 2 functions. The first function will use the WordPress filter hook for “the_content” to add the class of “entry-content” to the article. To add in the other essential hAtom fields, the second function will add a short sentence to the end of your post article, which contains updated time, post title and author, with required microdata.